# Attaching jquery datepicker to injected element

Tags: jquery, uidatepicker

How can i attach datepicker to dynamically injected element?

I cant simply make something like:

```
$(function(){
  $('.date').datepicker();
})
```

because after the dom complete loaded, there is no element with class of '.date'

I dont think `live()` will also work here

I got this error in firebug `$(".date").datepicker is not a function`

**Edit:**
This is how the element being injected

```
$('#typeId').change(function(){
   $(this).nextAll().remove();
   $(this).parent().append('<input type="hidden" name ="view_type" value="by_range"> <span>Start:</span> <input type="text" name="start_date" class="date"> <span>End:</span> <input type="text" name="end_date" class="date"> <input type="submit" value="Submit">');
})
```

Comment: do u want to update date dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Live Query](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery) did solve my problem

```
$('.date').livequery(){
  $(this).datepicker()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and create a callback function that will be called when the dynamically injected element is inserted. The callback could setup the datepicker for the specified selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you know when the element is inserted you can do .datepicker() on it right after that.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago i made something similar using Duplicate/Remove, a jQuery plugin you can find here: http://www.trovster.com/lab/plugins/duplicate-remove/

Right after the following on line 60 of jquery.duplicate-remove.js:

```
$(this).find('input').focus();
```

You can instantiate jQuery datepicker:

```
$(this).find('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

And then, just call Duplicate/Remove normally. You'll also need an "initial" instance of datepicker for the first element of the picker.

Comment: You can, of course, make this much more elegantly, allowing different instances of different jQuery UI elements, maybe even based on field name or id. I don't know. Just giving you the right tools for the job! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code to this:

```
$('#typeId').change(function(){
   $(this).nextAll().remove();
   $(this).parent().append($('<input type="hidden" name ="view_type" value="by_range"> <span>Start:</span> <input type="text" name="start_date" class="date"> <span>End:</span> <input type="text" name="end_date" class="date"> <input type="submit" value="Submit">').find('.date').datepicker());
})
```

Comment: not working, its not even append the form control...btw i have found the solution by using the live query plugin..thx for ur suggestion btw